# Show that a random walk on a finite grid graph is recurrent

Tags: probability, graph-theory, markov-process, random-walk

I want to show that a random walk on a graph is recurrent.  The graph is a network of nodes which connect together to make a $N \times M$ rectangular grid, [such as this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aq261.png), my first thought was to somehow get an expression for

$\mathbb{P}[\text{on node}\ n\ \text{after}\ i\ \text{jumps}|\text{on node}\ 0\ \text{at}\ i=0]$,

then express

$\mathbb{P}[\text{on node}\ 0\ \text{after}\ i\ \text{jumps}|\text{on node}\ 0\ \text{at}\ i=0]$

then let $i\to\infty$ and hope it $=1$.

Does this sound like the right approach? Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an explicit expression.  Any irreducible Markov chain on a finite state space is recurrent.

Comment: So what I really need to show is that the chain is irreducible?

Comment: And that amounts to showing that the graph is connected, i.e. it is possible to walk from any vertex to any other vertex.

Comment: Even if the graph is not connected, assuming you start on vertex $a$, can you not always return to vertex $a$, thus making it recurrent?

Comment: True.  Random walk on any finite (undirected) graph is recurrent.  A transient state would have to be a vertex $x$ such that for some $y$, it is possible to go from $x$ to $y$ but not possible to go from $y$ to $x$.